# SimpleJdbcCall for Function Without Parameters

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I have an Oracle Stored Function that returns a ref cursors but takes no input parameters.

Code is below:

```java
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getLoginProperties() {
        
        SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                .withCatalogName("LOGIN_PKG")
                .withFunctionName("get_login_properties")
                .returningResultSet("props", new HashMapRowMapper());
        Map<String, String> result = call.executeFunction(HashMap.class);
        return result;
    }
```

`HashMapRowMapper` is custom (currently barely implemented) code to return the results of the call as a `HashMap`, couldn't find an existing implementation to do it.

This code is throwing a `SQLException` due to missing IN or OUT parameter at index: 1. I've tried passing an empty `SqlParameterSource` with no luck.

Probably a simple issue, can anyone help?

Jason

EDIT: The function returns an Oracle ref cursor. Exception below. Line "68" refers to the line that `executeFunction` is on.

```java
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call LOGIN_PKG.GET_LOGIN_PROPERTIES()}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1542)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:395)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:193)
    at org.jason.app.repository.UserRepositoryImpl.getLoginProperties(UserRepositoryImpl.java:68)
    at org.jason.app.repository.UserRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$678318db.invoke(<generated>)
    (snip)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2018)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3736)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3941)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1010)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$call$6(JdbcTemplate.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1190)
    ... 83 more
```

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace you get and you probably want to return a `Map` and not the implementation `HashMap`.

Comment: Stacktrace added.

Comment: Have you tried adding `withNamedBinding`? As you are using names in the binding for the result. Make sure that the name used matches the name used in the function.

Comment: I just added that with an intentionally wrong parameter name just to try to get a different exception, same error. I honestly don't care if I get this by index or named parameter, I just need the result.

Comment: As stated have you tried with `withnamedBinding` in your setup? Also make sure it matches the name (also in casing etc.) as used in your function.

Comment: I have added ```withNamedBinding()``` and confirmed that the package name and function name matches (casing, spelling, etc). Same error. I added ```.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()``` which eliminated the error, but I can't exactly convert the results to a hashmap if I can't get the column name from the ```ResultSetMetaData```, so it definitely wasn't a solution.